# What is the difference of using `unionMoveSelector` versus putting selectors directly under `localSearch` configuration

Tags: configuration, optaplanner

In the [Optaplanner documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.28.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#combiningMultipleMoveSelectors) the behavior of `unionMoveSelector` is explained (it selects one move from the union of all child moves). But I cannot find any information, what is the behavior if one puts multiple selectors directly under `<localSearch>`.

Does it consider only the first selector, or it behaves the same, but without the possibility of any configuration? The algorithm runs without complaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only put one move selector in a LocalSearchPhaseConfig, so this will not parse:

```
<localSearch>
    <changeMoveSelector/>
    <swapMoveSelector/><!-- will fail to parse -->
</localSearch>
```

In the Java API it's even more clear: `LocalSearchPhaseConfig.setMoveSelectorConfig()` does not accept a list.

So the correct form is:

```
<localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>
        <changeMoveSelector/>
        <swapMoveSelector/>
    </unionMoveSelector>
</localSearch>
```

Local Search does a number of steps, and for each step it evaluates a number of selected moves, of one will be the winning move (AKA the step).

Each time Local Search needs to evaluate a move, it asks its move selector to generate a move. This is by default random JUST_IN_TIME. When that move selector is a union move selector with 2 child selectors, as configured above, it randomly picks one of those 2 child selectors and asks that selected move selector to generate a move.

So if the change move selector has 20 moves and the swap move selector has 50 moves, every change move has a 1 out of 40 chance of being selected, and every swap move has a 1 out of 100 chance of being selected. At least by default  (with random JUST_IN_TIME).